# Talkback reading the appname for each activity

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

When i'm navigating in my app. Talkback tells me the name of the app in each new Activity.

I would like to know if this is expected behaviour. If not, what can i do about it

I can't find anything about this on https://developer.android.com/training/accessibility

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**What's happening :** The talkback announces the activity label . If an activity label is not explicitly defined using **android:label=""** in the activity tag then the talkback will announce the app label defined in **android:label="@string/app_name"** in the application tag.

**Solution** : Specify the text you want to be announced for each activity in the activity tag. If you want the announcement to go silent for launch of a specific activity put android:label as empty string in that activity's tag.

Comment: But If you set the label of your launcher activity as empty. Your app will also have an empty name on the Phone home screen. To avoid this you can let the android:label of your launcher activity as appname and call setTiitle as empty in onCreate

Comment: Just tried this approach. You set the label on the activity tag with an empty string ("") and talkback reads "untitled", which isn´t what we´re trying to achieve here either.

If you use "@null" like for contentDescription, it goes back to reading the app name set on the manifest app label.

Comment: how about space (" ")